# Rvest: html_text() is scraping only first paragraph of the body of text

Tags: r, rvest

I have tried both html_text() and html_text2(). I'm trying to web scrape a news article which have multiple paragraphs, but only the first paragraph is showing up in R.

```
library(rvest)
read_html("https://ethiopianmonitor.com/2021/08/27/prime-minister-abiy-attends-g20-compact-with-africa-meeting/") %>%
    html_node("#content p")%>%
    html_text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `html_node` with `html_nodes` should works.

Comment: @purple1437 If you think this is the correct answer, please accept it.